Do marginal distribution and conditional distribution together pin down the joint distribution?
Suppose $X$ is a (one-dimensional) random variable following a normal distribution. And conditional on every value of $X$, $\vec{u}$ (a multidimensional random vector) follows a jointly normal distribution. Do the above conditions imply $\left(X, \vec{u}\right)$ follow a jointly normal distribution?

This may be a counter example to what you're stating. I read it a long time ago when I was working in MCMC. I found it enlightening at the time but I can't remember much about it now. https://statistics.fas.harvard.edu/files/statistics-2/files/xlm_amstat45-2_125-126_1991.pdf?m=1598553472

If the conditional mean of $U$ does not depend on $X$ in a linear way of if the conditional variance of $U$ depends on $X$ the joint is not normal.

@mlofton Thank you for the example! But I think they are referring to "$x|y$ and $y|x$ are both normal" while my question is "$x$ normal and $y|x$ normal".

@Xi'an Then if the mean depends on $X$ in a linear way and the conditional variance of $U$ does not depend on $X$, must it be jointly normal? Actually, this paper (https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/opre.33.2.427) motivates my question.

@Ypbor: if you have a specific question about this paper, you should post it as another question.  People are not going to read the paper, otherwise.

By "follows a normal distribution" do you mean the conditional distributions are all the same normal distribution or just some normal distribution that could vary with $X$?

For the general case in the title: $f_{X,Y}(x, y) = f_{X|Y}(x \mid y)f_Y(y)$ e.g. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution#Conditional_continuous_distributions, so the answer for that is yes (aside some edge cases perhaps, such as where the conditional becomes undefined)

@Ypbor: Yes, you are correct. My apologies for noise. Hopefully whuber and glen_b can guide you.
